# IOIO not connecting to PC, "waiting for handshake"

Tags: java, handshake, ioio

I, as well as many others, have had a problem with the IOIO OTG connecting with the PC, when building from eclipse.

We are using the ADT version of eclipse, with all libraries properly imported. When running the `HelloIOIOConsole` program, the console begins to connect, but hangs the connection. The last console message is `[console]: waiting for handshake`, and no error is thrown. The program will build, but the IOIO will not connect to the PC.

What causes this, and how can we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the problem: We did not specify the COM port.

We were able to fix this by going into eclipse ADT, under `Run` > `Run Configuration` > `variables` tab, and adding the line `-Dioio.SerialPorts=COMXX`, where XX is the COM port that the IOIO is connected to, to the `VM variables` box.

After adding `-Dioio.SerialPorts=COMXX`, it no longer checked every single COM port, which was causing the program to skip over the proper port.

As we were using the `COM16` USB port, we added the line `-Dioio.SerialPorts=COM16` which removed all connection issues and were able to run the program flawlessly.

Comment: Hey thanks for postign this answer - much appreciated.

Comment: @Tukajo Not a problem. In the future, you may want to just get your answer and leave on older questions, as this question is over a year old (16 months, to be exact)